# Can "percentage-wise" be used as adjective?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, adjectives, word-usage

Good afternoon.

I know all languages have exceptions.

But I can't find any cases where "percentage-wise" which is adverb is used as an adjective.

Since I have encountered the the phrase " identify ........... by one of percentage-wise and optimal gross margin", I am so confused.

How should I interpret the sentence? I think that the sentence means ".. by one of percentage-wise margin and optimal gross margin." but then, "percentage-wise" should be adjective. :< Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest, if you agree with my answer below, that you update the context and punctuation of the phrase. It seems to be inaccurately transcribed.

Answer (score 2):

You've asked two questions.

(1) Can "percentage-wise" be used as an adjective.

Yes.  "The percentage-wise method of calculating the metric has many advantages."

(2) What's the interpretation of "by one of [percentage-wise and optimal gross margin](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22percentage-wise+and+optimal+gross+margin%22)" which is taken from [Patent US 7979299 B1](http://www.google.com/patents/US7979299).

Part of the issue is that quote has been taken out of it's context.  Also, it's missing some of the original punctuation.  Here's the original context, as taken from [Patent US7979299](http://www.google.com/patents/US7979299):

> ## Methods and apparatus for optimizing markdown pricing
>
> CLAIMS(14)
>
> 1. A method of optimizing scheduling of markdown pricing for one or more related items at a plurality of retail sites, the method comprising:
>
> for each retail site in the plurality of retail sites, identifying a type of related items based, at least in part on, whether markdown schedules for individual items would be substantially similar if optimized separately;
>
> determining which retail sites from the plurality of retail sites have similar metrics, the metrics identifying which retail sites are equally close to selling out the type of related items **by one of, percentage-wise and optimal gross margin,** given a current price of the type of related items;  **[NOTE: emphasis added for this question/answer only]**

Note that among legal documents, patents are notoriously difficult to interpret. In fact, interpretations of the meanings of patents are often *decided in court within the context of an infringement of patent lawsuit!*

When the phrase "by one of" is followed by a comma, colon, or "the following", it might suggest a listing of separate items. But other times, not.  Let's consider another sentence which may be a bit easier to comprehend:

- "He can make great food ***by one of, spicy and hot recipes,*** to which said patent Section 6 does forth suggest patently patent stuff stuff stuff..."

Now does this mean "spicy, hot recipes" or "spicy recipes and hot recipes"?  Since we have a list, it must be the latter. But additional sentence complexity can make it more ambiguous.  Practically speaking, the answer could very well depend on what is decided in a court of law.

Answer (score 0):

> identify (something) by one **of percentage-wise** and optimal gross margin.

At best it does not seem natural. What is the source and context?

I think it would be better said as:

> identify (something) **by percentage** and optimal gross margin

or

> identify (something) **by means of percentage** and optimal gross margin

Comment: It's from patent context. so I can't omit 'one of'. So, 'percentage-wise margin' is acceptable?

Comment: The usage of "percentage-wise" in the example does not make sense to me. What does "percentage-wise" refer to? It seems like a description of something else, but that needs to be established to think of *percentage-wise* as an adjective.